# BIZZARE OUTPUT. SHOULDN'T OUTPUT BE 153 INSTEAD OF 152

Tags: c, output, pow

```
int main()
{

  char arr[3]={'1','5','3'};
  int sum=0;
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
     sum+=pow((arr[i]-48),3);

     printf("%d to the power 3 is: %f\n",arr[i]-48,pow((arr[i]-48),3));
  }
 printf("sum is %d\n",sum);
}
```

Expected Output:

```
1 to the power 3 is: 1.000000
5 to the power 3 is: 125.000000
3 to the power 3 is: 27.000000
sum is 153
```

Actual Output:

```
1 to the power 3 is: 1.000000
5 to the power 3 is: 125.000000
3 to the power 3 is: 27.000000
sum is 152
```

[Here is an image of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDDmB.png)

Shouldn't the output be 153 and **NOT** 152?

Edit: If instead of sum+=pow((arr[i]-48),3); i use
                    sum+=(int)(floor(pow((arr[i]-48),3)));

OUTPUT IS CORRECTLY COMING AS 153. So i don't thing pow returning the smaller integer or for that matter type casting of float to integer returning the smaller value is the case over here

Comment: Its probably floating point inaccuracy. You're casting it to an int and the floating point value is probably 152.9999999 something. Casting that to int results in 152.

Comment: My previous statement is incorrect. the casting is done in the addition to the sum. There is the problem probably. Same problem origin as my previous comment.

Comment: @Lundin: If Microsoft Visual Studio gave an answer that was too low in integer division, would you consider it an integer arithmetic problem or a Microsoft defect? If the latter, why do you consider the fact that Microsoft `pow` gives an answer too low, when the correct result could in fact be returned, to be a floating-point arithmetic problem?

Comment: @Neijwiert if that was the case then instead of sum+=pow((arr[i]-48),3); if i used             sum+= (int)(floor(pow((arr[i]-48),3))); the answer should have been 152 only. However ans is 153. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft `pow` routine is notoriously bad. It is possible to return correct results for these and similar operands, as the macOS `pow` demonstrates, but Microsoft either has not put in the engineering work to do this or has chosen not to change their `pow` implementation. Even for small integer operands with mathematical results that are representable in floating-point, `pow` may return results that are slightly larger or slightly smaller than the correct value. When returns a result smaller than the exact integer result, then converting it to an integer results in truncation to the next lower integer.

Computing `pow` is difficult, and not all implementations do a good job. For floating-point functions, the best quality theoretically possible is *correctly rounded*. A correctly rounded routine returns the number representable in the floating-point format that is closest to the exact mathematical result, rounded in a direction governed by a chosen rounding rule. (The most commonly used rounding rule is to round to the nearest value, with ties toward the even low digit. Other rules include rounding toward +∞, toward −∞, and toward zero.) It is very difficult to compute `pow` with correct rounding, and no commercial or commonly used implementation I am aware of does so.

Nevertheless, it is possible to design `pow` so that it returns the exact result whenever the exact result is representable in the floating-point format. As I recall, the current `macOS` pow implementation does this. Thus, the program in the question, when compiled and executed with macOS tools, will produce the expected results. Microsoft’s `pow` does not have this property, so computing `pow(x, 3)` may return a value slightly less than *x*<sup>3</sup>, even when *x*<sup>3</sup> is representable.

Even if one is using a high-quality `pow` implementation, it is generally desirable not to use `pow` with small integer powers for reasons of speed. Computing `pow(x, 3)` is slower than computing `x*x*x`.